# Why the child view parameter changed without view updated?

Tags: swiftui

The child view has a "hostDate" parameter that the child view used for get async data and displays in its view. The parent view has a button that trigger the change of the child view parameter.

Below is my demo code

```
struct Parent: View {
    
    @State var dayOffset: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Child(hostDate: Date().add(days: dayOffset))
            Button("Change day offset") {
                dayOffset += 1
            }
        }
    }
}


struct Child: View {
    
    let hostDate: Date
    
    @State var taskCount: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Text("host date is \(hostDate.description)")
            Text(" Task count is \(taskCount)")
        }
        .task {
            let summary = await DailySummary.of(hostDate)
            taskCount = summary.taskCount
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make it get async data every time the parameter changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `hostDate` become @State in Parent and @Binding in Child. Then mapping with each other.

@State means this property is stored in ParentView.

@Binding means this property will be provided from elsewhere, and will be shared.

```swift
struct ParentView: View {
    @State private var hostDate = Date()
    @State private var dayOffSet = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            ChildView(hostDate: $hostDate)
            
            Button {
                dayOffSet += 1
                hostDate.add(days: dayOffSet)
            } label: {
                Text("Change day offset")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var hostDate: Date
    ...
}
```

Comment: Do you mind marking it as the correct answer if it helps?

Comment: Yes, actually I already did.But it says I need at least 15 reputation to make a vote... This is my first question..

Comment: Aw, it's up voting rule, I mean https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Ok, I did it.thank you,man

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

**1. store 2 different `State` variables and pass a `Binding` of `hostDate`.**

```swift
struct Parent: View {
    
    @State private var dayOffset: Int = 0

    // Change to nil or your default value
    @State private var hostDate: Date = .now
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Child(hostDate: $hostDate)
            Button("Change day offset") {
                dayOffset += 1
                // You can either update the value here or using `.onChange`
                //hostDate = Date().add(days: dayOffset)
            }
        }
        // This approach is a best practice
        .onChange(of: dayOffset) { oldValue, newValue in
            hostDate = Date().add(days: dayOffset)
        }
    }
}


struct Child: View {
    
    @Binding var hostDate: Date
    
    @State private var taskCount: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        // The rest of your code 
    }
}
```

**2. but a better approach would be to, pass the `dayOffset` as a `Binding` to the child view, and calculate `hostDate` in the child view.**

```swift
struct Parent: View {
    
    @State private var dayOffset: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Child(dayOffset: $dayOffset)
            Button("Change day offset") {
                dayOffset += 1
            }
        }
    }
}


struct Child: View {

    @Binding var dayOffset: Date
    
    @State private var taskCount: Int = 0

    private var hostDate: Date {
        Date().add(days: dayOffset)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        // The rest of your code
    }
}
```